# use Python to call ImageMagick's "import"

Tags: python, imagemagick

I want to capture a screenshot of an application's window from a Python script using ImageMagick, as I would with ImageMagick's "import" command from a shell. An API call or a system call from Python (as in "subprocess.Popen(["import"...") will suffice, but I don't want to create a file on the hard drive. My OS is Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the command:

```
import png:-
```

This will cause `import` to output to stdout.

You can also change `png` to one of the type tags shown [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).