# Send args to subprocess while using stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdin, io-redirection

I'm trying to take a screenshot then run a command on that screenshot without saving to disk.

The actual command I want to run is `visgrep image.png pattern.pat`

`visgrep` must have two args: the image file and a .pat file.

Here is what I have so far.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['import', '-crop', '305x42+1328+281', '-window', 'root', '-depth', '8', 'png:' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
cmd = ['visgrep']
subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=p.stdout)
```

Obviously this fails as visgrep must have two args.

So how can I do `visgrep image.png pattern.pat` but substituting 'image.png' with the output of ImageMagick's `import`?

Do I need to use xargs? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux you can use `/dev/stdin` as file name but it does not work all the times. If it does not work with `visgrep`, you must use a temporary file (which is not a shame).

PS. shouldn't `png:`  be `png:-`?

Comment: Thank you! /dev/stdin works. Yes, it was png:- but I removed the - for no reason whatsoever and it made no noticeable difference so forgot to add it back on.

Comment: @JayS: sometimes a mere `-` also works: `import .. | visgrep - pat`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590088/use-python-to-call-imagemagicks-import), changing the argument `png:` to `png:-` will cause the import command to output to standard out instead of a file. I am unfamiliar with visgrep, so I'm not sure how to tell it to read the source image from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php):

> **STDIN, STDOUT, and file descriptors**
>
> Unix and Windows permit the output of one command to be piped to the
>   input of another. ImageMagick permits image data to be read and
>   written from the standard streams STDIN (standard in) and STDOUT
>   (standard out), respectively, using a pseudo-filename of -. In this
>   example we pipe the output of convert to the display program:
>
> `$ convert logo: gif:- | display gif:-`
>
> The second explicit format "gif:" is optional in the preceding
>   example. The GIF image format has a unique signature within the image
>   so ImageMagick's display command can readily recognize the format as
>   GIF. The convert program also accepts STDIN as input in this way:
>
> $ `convert rose: gif:- | convert - -resize "200%" bigrose.jpg`

You can use the same filename convention with the `import` command.

So, try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['import', '-crop', '305x42+1328+281', 
                      '-window', 'root', '-depth', '8', 'png:-' ], 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
```